# Why is __getLastResponse and the var where I stored the request result returning different values?

Tags: php, soap

I'm using SOAP to consume a webservice. After connect I make this request:

```
$result = $_client->CREATE_CUSTOMER(array('COLECAO_CLIENTES' => $cliente));
```

When I call the __getLastResponse() method I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><CREATE_CUSTOMERRESPONSE xmlns="http://187.94.60.223:788/"><CREATE_CUSTOMERRESULT>Required data not sent.</CREATE_CUSTOMERRESULT></CREATE_CUSTOMERRESPONSE></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

But when I print $result I got this:

```
object(stdClass)#141 (1) {
  ["CREATE_CUSTOMERRESULT"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Could someone help me to understand this?

UPDATE:

I checked the  in the wsdl of the webservice and the result is a string. Code follows below:

```
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CREATE_CUSTOMERRESULT" type="s:string"/>
```

Comment: How you are able to get the last _response_ with `__getLastRequest()` is what I want to know... Divining an answer would be that the SOAP implementation on the server is broken, and `<CREATE_CUSTOMERRESULT>` is defined as a boolean, and rather then sending a proper soap error, they abuse it's contents. PHP expects either false or true, and chooses true as the contents is not 'false'.

Comment: Sorry, man. I just mixed me up while writing this question. In my code I'm calling __getLastResponse. I edited the question now. I checked the wsdl and the type of the <CREATE_CUSTOMERRESULT> is string. I just updated the description of the question with this.

Comment: I can't give all the wsdl as it is a private project of the company I work at. But the part refering to the atribute I'm working on is now in the description of the question.

Comment: Keep in mind entries with those names can occur several times under different guises. Without the wsdl all I can say is it works here, see for a testcase:http://pastebin.com/MX4W8Z01